# FLOSS Duplicate Email Detector For PSTs?

Tags: email, outlook

Does anyone have a 'FLOSS' (free/libre/open source software) duplicate email detector that will search Outlook PST files and compare emails in the same folder and find duplicates?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the duplicates are the result of a recent import process, you may be able to remove them without a utility using the process described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299349).  I can't vouch for it, but [Vaita Outlook Duplicate Items Remover](http://www.vaita.com/ODIR.asp) claims to do the job and is free, but is not open source.

Comment: Vaita Outlook Duplicate Items Remover does the job!